# Can i get satellites names in android?It shows me in their SNR,PNR,elevation,azimuth but i don't know if the data that it shows me is correct

Tags: android

```
  package my.pack;

  import java.util.Iterator;

  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.content.Context;
  import android.location.GpsSatellite;
  import android.location.GpsStatus;
  import android.location.GpsStatus.NmeaListener;
  import android.location.Location;
  import android.location.LocationListener;
  import android.location.LocationManager;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.util.Log;
  import android.widget.Toast;

  public class SatellitesActivity extends Activity {
LocationManager locMgr;
double lat;
double lon;
  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

     locMgr = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
     MyGpsListener listener = new MyGpsListener();
     MyLocationListener locListener = new MyLocationListener();
     locMgr.addGpsStatusListener(listener);      
     locMgr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locListener);
     locMgr.addNmeaListener(new NmeaListener() {

        @Override
        public void onNmeaReceived(long timestamp, String nmea) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.e("Test!", nmea);
        }
    });

   }



  public class MyGpsListener implements GpsStatus.Listener{
    @Override
    public void onGpsStatusChanged(int event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(event){
        case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STARTED:Log.e("Started", "");
            break;
        case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_FIRST_FIX:Log.e("FirstFix", "");
            break;
        case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STOPPED:Log.e("Sopped", "");
            break;
        case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS:GpsStatus xGpsStatus = locMgr.getGpsStatus(null) ; 
        Iterable<GpsSatellite> iSatellites = xGpsStatus.getSatellites() ; 
        Iterator<GpsSatellite> it = iSatellites.iterator() ; 
        while ( it.hasNext() ) 
        { 
                GpsSatellite oSat = (GpsSatellite) it.next() ; 
                if(oSat.usedInFix()){
                    Log.e("A fost folosit ", "int fix!");
                }
                if(oSat.toString()!=null){

                    Log.e("Test", "SNR:"+oSat.getSnr()+"; Azimuth:"+oSat.getAzimuth()+"; Elevation:"+oSat.getElevation()+" "+oSat.toString()+"; PRN:"+oSat.getPrn());
                }
        } 
        break ; 


        }
    }
    }

public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener{

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(location!=null){
            lat = location.getLatitude();
            lon = location.getLongitude();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+lat+"\n"+lon, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }}
```

}

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answers.I found this http://www.n2yo.com/whats-up/?c=20 and i hope the data here is correct.I'll work on my app and when is ready i'll post the code here.Untill then i will have more questions.

Comment: Useful example code on how to get azimuth, elevation of the satellites...

Comment: I will not tell you my name :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Satellites don't really have names that you can grab. The best you can get is the PRN, which your code already shows you getting.

**Edit**
After some more reading, I have found that some people have attempted to map PRN numbers even though sometimes this is incorrect. Try http://www.losangeles.af.mil/shared/media/document/AFD-070530-036.pdf

Comment: Well,it may be so but i found an application called SatelliteAR and there all satellites had names like "EchoStar"etc.Can i find somewhere the correspondence between PRN and names?

Answer (score 0):

You could map the PRN number to the satellite name using your own code, based on some reference on the internet (e.g. [List of GPS satellites](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_GPS_satellites)). I'm not aware of any kind of automatic PRN decoding service that decodes the PRN number to a satellite name. Please note that the Department of Defense is free to re-allocate PRN numbers to different satellites when they see fit. So for example, if [USA-66](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USA-66) dies tomorrow, they are likely to re-allocate (eventually) another satellite to PRN 32.